# HTML/Body does not encapsulate entire height

Tags: html, css

This is a quick mock-up to create a full-size webpage, however whenever I test this, a small margin of space is present at the top of the screen.

How can I get rid of this small space at the top?

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="header">
        <div class="header_container">
            <h1 class="header_logo">Blog</h1>
            <nav class="menu_nav">
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}

.header_container{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is being caused by the margin on the top of the h1.

To fix this, either give the header a property of `overflow:hidden` to make the header taller, or remove the margin of the h1 using `margin-top:0`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/8QV4f/

Comment: The classic collapsing margin syndrome!

Comment: Could you explain why that happens?

Comment: @TheSunny I think it's kind of described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), but the basic principle is that the margin, instead of moving just the h1, leaks outside and moves the container. My understanding ends at figuring out what is happening. I don't exactly understand why.